# GridSearchCV seems like does not evaluate all the parameters that I am providing for it

Tags: python-3.x, keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning, grid-search

in my code I am trying to evaluate which combination of parameters is best for my ANN accuracy. But It seems like my GridSearchCV only checks the first value for each parameter and returns the best combination of parameters the first inputs of values for those parameters.
here is my code:

```
import keras
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

def build_classifier(optimizer):
    classifier = Sequential()
    classifier.add(Dense(6, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu', input_dim= 11))
    classifier.add(Dense(6, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
    classifier.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
    classifier.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
    return classifier

classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn= build_classifier)
parameters = {'batch_size':[25,32], 'nb_epoch':[500,100], 'optimizer': ['rmsprop', 'adam']}

grid_search =GridSearchCV(estimator = classifier, param_grid= parameters, scoring= 'accuracy', cv=10)

grid_search= grid_search.fit(x_train, y_train)
best_parameters= grid_search.best_params_
best_accuracy=grid_search.best_score_
```

at this moment what it returns is best parameters are : batch size= 25, epoch = 500 and optimizer = 'rmsprop'

now if I change my parameters to :

```
parameters = {'batch_size':[25,32], 'nb_epoch':[100,500], 'optimizer': ['adam', 'rmsprop']}
```

it returns best parameters as batch_size = 25, epoch=100 and Optimizer =adam

and in console I see this:

```
Epoch 1/1
7200/7200 [==============================] - 0s 49us/step - loss: 0.6335 - accuracy: 0.7928
Epoch 1/1
7200/7200 [==============================] - 0s 52us/step - loss: 0.6166 - accuracy: 0.7937
Epoch 1/1
7200/7200 [==============================] - 0s 59us/step - loss: 0.5946 - accuracy: 0.7956
Epoch 1/1
7200/7200 [==============================] - 0s 58us/step - loss: 0.6066 - accuracy: 0.7942
Epoch 1/1
7200/7200 [==============================] - 0s 61us/step - loss: 0.5923 - accuracy: 0.7932
Epoch 1/1
7200/7200 [==============================] - 0s 61us/step - loss: 0.5829 - accuracy: 0.7971
Epoch 1/1
7200/7200 [==============================] - 0s 54us/step - loss: 0.6069 - accuracy: 0.7924
Epoch 1/1
7200/7200 [==============================] - 0s 57us/step - loss: 0.6115 - accuracy: 0.7921
Epoch 1/1
7200/7200 [==============================] - 0s 58us/step - loss: 0.5892 - accuracy: 0.7944
Epoch 1/1
7200/7200 [==============================] - 0s 59us/step - loss: 0.5905 - accuracy: 0.7951
Epoch 1/1
7200/7200 [==============================] - 0s 59us/step - loss: 0.5726 - accuracy: 0.7957
Epoch 1/1
7200/7200 [==============================] - 0s 59us/step - loss: 0.5940 - accuracy: 0.7944
Epoch 1/1
8000/8000 [==============================] - 0s 55us/step - loss: 0.5755 - accuracy: 0.7946
```

Why it is always epoch 1/1??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter for epochs is called `epochs`, not `nb_epoch`, this was change in Keras 2.0. You need to put the right name or it will assume a value.

About the best parameters, there is always some randomness associated to training a neural network (due to random weight initialization), so you should not interpret the results like you are doing, as it could just be because of chance.

Comment: Regarding best parameters, can you please kindly explain to me how should I interpret the results so that I can avoid chance?